# Can I build a file by mmap incrementally?

Tags: python, python-2.7, pickle, mmap

I'm new to python. I'm trying to build a local DB for a huge data by mmap. 
Data are written as:

```
import os
import mmap
import cPickle as pickle
import operator
from functools32 import lru_cache
with open(path + '.data', 'wb') as f:
    index = []
    for key, value in iter_kvs:
        index.append((key, f.tell()))
        mmdict.serialise(value, f)
with open(path + '.index','wb') as f:
    mmdict.serialise(index, f)
```

The issue is that my machine is unable to complete a process of the whole dataset and store at once. What I would like to know for instance, if in one run the word `cat` was used as an index and the value is `10` and in the next run on a different partition of the data `cat` was again found with value `15`, will the first index be updated? or will a new index be added?

I will be glad to update the question to provide more info if recquired.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: I think we would need specific details on your data structure `mmdict` and what its `serialise` function does. Is this from your own code or a library? Whether the index file position is updated also probably depends on whatever your custom `index` object's `append` function does. If `index` is a `list`, then yes, you'll get multiple entries.

Comment: Separately, from the Python docs on `mmap`, note that, "Assignment to an `ACCESS_WRITE` memory map affects both memory and the underlying file." So if the eventual overall size of the data is too large for memory, you'll still need to manually manage this in your program, for example by unmapping parts of the data no longer needed.

Comment: @ely No it's from and API and here this link of the file I'm referencing which I think has the info you asked https://github.com/wikilinks/nel/blob/master/nel/model/store/file.py Thanks

Comment: @ely The program runs on pyspark but still too huge to complete a the process on the entire data file.

Comment: @ely I updated the question to show more details. To the best of my knowledge index seems to be a list from `index = []`. Thank you.